# Firefox on Android - site's mobile menu partially visible

Tags: html, css

On my site and only on Firefox for Android, the mobile menu is partially visible and actually covers the mobile hamburger menu and things seem kind of not scaled properly. I have view port tag as follows now but didn't help:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.86, shrink-to-fit=no, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=0.86">
```

[image]

Its fine on all other mobile browsers.

Comment: what's your code?

Comment: updated the post with my code

Comment: Any ideas on what the issue could be?